# Show that $\sigma_p(T) \subset \sigma_p(T_1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let, $T$ be a bounded operator and $T_1$ an extension of $T$. Show that, Show that $\sigma_p(T) \subset \sigma_p(T_1)$. Further, show that for any $\lambda \in \sigma_p(T)$ the eigenspace of $T$ is contained in eigenspace of $T_1$.

For the first part this is my attempt:

Let, $Y \subseteq X$ and $T: Y \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Extending $T$ to $T_1$ such that $T_1 : X \rightarrow X$ and $T_1\big|_{Y} = T$. For any $\lambda \in \sigma_p(T_1) \ \exists \ x(\neq 0) \in X$ such that $T_1(x) = \lambda x$. If $x \notin Y$ then $\lambda \notin \sigma_p(T)$. Again, if $\lambda \in \sigma_p(T)$ then $\exists \ x \in Y \subseteq X$ such that $Tx = \lambda x \implies T_1x = \lambda x \implies \lambda \in \sigma_p(T_1)$. Thus, $\sigma_p(T) \subset \sigma_p(T_1)$.

Am I doing it correctly ?

I have no idea how to show the second part. Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is correct. You have also proved that any eigen vector corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda$ of $T$ is an eigen vector of $T_1$ corresponding to that eigen value. Hence  the eigen space of $T$ corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda$ is contained in the eigen space of $T$ corresponding to that eigen value.

Eigen space corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda$ is simply the space spanned by all the eigen vectors corresponding to $\lambda$.